# get/setClientInfo() in SQL Server with Third Party Driver

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

The organization I work at has our Java applications connect to a SQL Server database, each with its own unique application ID.  However, individual users of the application itself (web site users, etc) will all access the database through this single application ID, making auditing difficult (eg. we can't tell which Java application user deleted a row, just that someone using the application did).

I've looked into `setClientInfo()` and `getClientInfo()` in the JDBC Connection class.  Apparently this is not currently supported in Microsoft's current JDBC driver.

Does this imply that SQL Server itself also does not support this functionality? (I'm currently experimenting with a third party driver from DataDirect that supposedly does support it, but I don't know if the information is actually getting propagated to and/or logged by the database).
If this is supported, where is the ClientUser information (set by `setClientInfo()`) stored/logged in the DBMS?

I appreciate any ideas or feedback.

Comment: After more research it looks like SQL Server does not, in fact, support this functionality.  The setClientInfo() and getClientInfo() methods appear to work when using DataDirect's driver, but the ID is being cached by the driver and not propagated on to SQL server itself.  It looks like others are sometimes using the CONTEXT_INFO field in SQL server for audit.